# One-To-Many relathionship task

Tags: database, database-normalization

I have a table `Subject`
It has many fields, two of them are `code` and `flag`.
Earlier those two fields was an idempotention key for rows in this table.
But, now I need one more option `system`.

There are tens of rows in `Subject`
And 4-7 systems.

What is a better way?

1. Create table `System` for systems and create cross-table of mapping sysytems on subjects (`code` and `flag` are still in table `Subject`)
2. Create one table of mapping without creating table `System`
3. Just add another column in table `Subject`
4. Create table `System` and add to the table `Subject` foreign key for table `System`?

So, It's all about database normalization.
And the third option is pretty bad.
As for me the better way is fourth option.
But, I can`t explain to yourself why this option is better than 1 and 2.
So, I read rules of database normalization. And as for me, the first option satisfies all rules too.

This is the reason why I am asking this question.

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of "Create one table of mapping"

Comment: Did you mean to imply a "linking table"? such as table `SystemSubject` with a PK `SystemSubjectId` and a FK to `System`  such as `SystemId` and another FK to `Subject` such as `SubjectId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not typically a great idea to design a SQL schema to 1st or 2nd normal form; many databases use something at or near 3rd normal form however there many still be some relationships in 3rd normal form where dependencies exist where redundancy still exists.  This can be addressed by Boyce–Codd Normal Form (Codd, 1974).

It is also not typical to see 4th normal form and less so 5th normal form and beyond due to challenges with data maintenance in a "living" database.

Let's put this another way.

If you find yourself creating `NULLable` values constraints on many columns consider a table to contain those in an organized fashion - for example an `Address` table for addresses with a linking table from say for example a Person to a `PersonAddress` linking table to that `Address` table where the `PersonAddress` linking table might even have an `AdddressTypeId` column which links to an `AddressType` table with rows for `Address Type Postal` and `Address Type Street` or `Address Type Business`.  For another example consider email addresses where people have personal, family, business and other email address types; even multiple of the same type for different uses; a doctor with a business practice email and 2-3 hospital email addresses where the doctor practices.

Linking tables for those type scenarios are likely better than 3-4 or more email or postal address columns in one table where many after the first are nullable or perhaps redundant.

Review your data; consider if your `Subject` for example may link to multiple `System` or placing a `SubjectId` column may lead to duplicates of that ID for differing system rows. If it is always and forever a 1-1 relationship it may be OK but for a 1-n or n-n it may not be ok to have the id in the other table and a linking table may provide a good mechanism to link them.